# EPS reader java

Tags: java, jmagick

I downloaded the library for working with EPS files [here](http://www.spectotechnologies.com/projets-ouverts/plugiciel-eps-pour-imageio).

And wrote some code to parse EPS file:

```
EPSImageReaderSPI spi = new EPSImageReaderSPI();
EPSImageReader eps = new EPSImageReader(spi);

File file = new File("file.eps");
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
ImageInputStream iis = null;
iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);
eps.setInput(iis);
eps.getHeight(0);
```

My code crashes and saying:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Data type -1 not supported
>       at epsLib.EPSImageReader.readHeader(EPSImageReader.java:307)
>       at epsLib.EPSImageReader.getHeight(EPSImageReader.java:148)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Can you help me please?

**UPDATED:**

When I try to install **jmagick**, but when I run the command:

```
./configure --with-java-home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current --with-magick-home=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10 --with-magick-inc-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include
```

Get this error:

> checking for MagickCore-config... /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/bin/MagickCore-config
>       /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/bin/MagickCore-config: line 50: pkg-config: command not found
>       /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/bin/MagickCore-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found
>       /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/bin/MagickCore-config: line 47: pkg-config: command not found
>       checking magick/api.h usability... no
>       checking magick/api.h presence... no
>       checking for magick/api.h... no
>       configure: error: Unable to find ImageMagick header files

---

**UPDATED:**

I fix it! Just change command to:

```
./configure --with-java-home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current --with-magick-home=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10 --with-magick-inc-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/
```

Then I tried:

```
make all
```

And get error:

> make[1](http://www.spectotechnologies.com/projets-ouverts/plugiciel-eps-pour-imageio): Entering directory `/Users/olegsuzaev/jmagick-6.4.0/src'make[2]: Entering directory`/Users/olegsuzaev/jmagick-6.4.0/src/magick'../../Make.rules:175: *** missing separator.  Stop.
>       make[2]: Leaving directory `/Users/olegsuzaev/jmagick-6.4.0/src/magick'
>       make[1]: *** [dir_target] Error 2
>       make[1]: Leaving directory`/Users/olegsuzaev/jmagick-6.4.0/src'
>       make: *** [dir_target] Error 2

Can somebody help with new error?

Comment: Glad you took my EPS reader, unfortunatly it doesn't support vectorial EPS files for the moment. Is you EPS containing vectorial data?

Comment: Hi! Yes it's contain.  
it's a pity that the library does not support vectorial EPS files. Do you know any other libraries that can help me? thanks a lot)

Comment: Sorry I don't know any Java lib, I would go like Amorgos said, JMagick. I developped this lib exactly because there is no one. At this time I doesn't needed the vectorial part.

Comment: Is it difficult to add the vectorial part in your library?

Comment: Sure, it is a project in itself. Here you have some information about how EPS files works : http://www.fileformat.info/format/eps/egff.htm. To parse vectorial, you need to read and interpret all vectorial commands. Example : /s /stroke ld /f /fill ld /m /moveto ld /l /lineto ld /c /curveto ld /rgb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you contact the author of this code or look at the code yourself to figure out why this exception is occurring.

As an alternative there seems to be a number of EPS APIs available for Java. Here are a few:

- [jlibeps](http://jlibeps.sourceforge.net/)
- [EPS Graphics API](http://www.abeel.be/epsgraphics/)
- [Jibble EPS](http://www.jibble.org/epsgraphics/)
- [Java EPS Graphics](https://github.com/matmas/java-eps-graphics)

Also, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (a C library) supports EPS to read EPS, and there's a JNI wrapper for ImageMagick called [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/) that allows access to ImageMagick from Java.

Comment: Each of them does not allow read data EPS file, they are designed to create EPS files (

Comment: I have found that Ghostscript works pretty well with EPS files but again I am trying to find a java wrapper that supports all operations using java. Ghost4j is one that I am exploring. Any suggestions what worked for you?